# Cannot ssh until pinging url

Tags: ssh, dns

If, after starting system (freshly installed Linux Mint 13), I try to run:

```
ssh mywebsite.com
```

it hangs up with "Connection timed out". but when I open the browser and enter mywebsite.com there (or even run ping), `ssh` suddenly starts working.

The same happens with one program accessing it's api through https. I cannot use it until I access api through the browser.

The same happens with rdp protocol. remmina/rdesktop don't work until i ping specific url.

Maybe it's dns related?

What can i do to debug/fix this issue?

Comment: How does your iptables/firewall look?

Comment: no rules, no firewall. router has nat enabled (no firewall too). i disabled almost everything while trying to debug that. took me 4 days including os reinstall to locate the problem..

Comment: Mint is off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by changing connection type to "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only" and specifying dns servers inside the connection. I suppose issue was with DNS or the router.